# How to send response using jest function? It gives async callback error

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I try to mock model response using jest. It will go in my jest.mock.createMondayBox function and it can print "hello world", which means it can really go inside mock model that replaces the original model.

models/mondayModel.js

```
var mondayModel = function() {
  function createBox (req, payload, callback) { 
   ...
   boxClient.request(req, {
     method: 'POST'
     path:
     body: 
     headers: { }
   }, function(error, response) {
      if(error || (response.statusCode && response.statusCode !== 200)) { 
        return callback(new ErrorObject({
           errorName:'createBoxFailure', 
           errorMessage: 'Error in creating box'
        })
      }
      return callback(null, {resultSet: response.body})
   })

  }
  function fnB (req, callback) { }
  function fnC (req, callback) { }
  function fnD (req, callback) { }
  return {
    createBox: createBox,
    fnB: fnB,
    fnC: fnC,
    fnD: fnD
  }
}

module.exports = mondayModel
```

controller/boxController.js

```
var MondayModel = require('../models/mondayModel');


function createMondayBox(req, res, next) {
   ...
   var mondayModel = new MondayModel();
   mondayModel.createBox(req, payload, function(error, result) {

      if(error) {
         res.json({'status': 'BADREQUEST', 'statusCode': 400})

      } else {
         var mondaybox = result.resultSet.mondayboxes && result.resultSet.mondayboxes[0]

         var mappedResponse = Response.mapCreateMondaybox(req, resultSet);
         utils.logKK(req, utils.getKK(mappedResponse.mondayboxes[0]))
         res.json(mappedResponse);
      }

   ...
   }
}
```

boxController-test.jest

```
let boxController = null

describe('money tracker', () => {
    beforeAll(() => {        
        jest.mock('../../../../models/mondayBox',
            () => function mondayBoxModel() {
               console.log("hello world")
               return {
                createBox: (req, payload, callback) => {
                  return callback(null, {
                        resultSet: {
                            mondayboxes: [{ name: '1' }, { name: '2' }]
                        },
                        json: jest.fn()
                    })}
                fnB: jest.fn(),
                fnC: jest.fn(),
                fnD: jest.fn()
                }
               }
        }))    
    )
        boxController = require('../controllers/boxController')
    })

    test('success case', done => {
       const req = {}
       const res = new Promise(r =>
         r({ json: jest.fn(), status: jest.fn() })
       )
       mondayBoxController.createMondayBox(req, res, (cbErr, cbRes) => {
          expect(res.json).toBeCalled();
          done()
       }) 
    }
}
```

TypeError: res.json is not a function

May I know how to solve this problem? How to write mock model response?
Thanks

Comment: You can't use mock function for `const res = jest.fn()`, you need to use function that return promise or async of object with json function `{json: () => 'JSON'}` and you should control the JSON, Also you use mock for mondayBox, which make no sens because this is what you should be testing, real implementation that call `res.json()` so it's called in your code, you don't called res because you mocked everything.

Comment: @jcubic sorry I think I only mock model. Since the controller will call model, which i want to avoid side effects. In that case, I need to mock the response of the model so that I can simulate different case I think. I do not understand why you say i mock everything?

Comment: I've check your code again, and it seems that you only need `const res = Promise.resolve({json: jest.fn()});` Looking at your code it seems that you should get error, that json is not defined. Also are you sure that you call `next` inside callback in `createMondayBox` function?

Comment: @jcubic I think the reason why call next is because of async?

Comment: if you don't call next then `(cbErr, cbRes) => ` below will not be called. You need to call next after you call `res.json()`. And one side note if res is standard fetch API then you will need to use `res.json(Promise.resolve({}))`.

Comment: ```const res = new Promise(r =>
                r({ json: jest.fn(), status: jest.fn() })
             boxController.createMondayBox(req, res, (cbErr, cbRes) => {expect(res.json(Promise.resolve({}))).toBeCalled() done()}
           )``` It will complain TypeError: res.json is not a function

Comment: this is the same as `Promise.resolve({ json: jest.fn(), status: jest.fn() })`

Comment: Sorry, I've confused myself. Is res part of the mock for fetch API?

Comment: yes, it is api call @jcubic

Comment: Then this is really messed up, Is you JS client code just one layer of top of fetch with it's own requests and responses and it's own status codes or `res` in your test is the thing from `fetch()`? Maybe you just showed not enough code.

Comment: @jcubic Hi I have updated the codes, and also currently it shows res.json is not function in test. Appreciate your patience and help.

Comment: replace this `expect(res.json(Promise.resolve({}))).toBeCalled()` with `expect(res.json).toBeCalled();` also now your call to `mondayModel.createBox(` is not executing none of the cases you show, you need to show your whole callback function. Including call to `next`. Do you have demo of this somewhere, it's in complete.

Comment: updated, but currently, it fails in the controller, res.json(mappedResponse), res.json is not function. Currently, I do not want to mock error case. Just success case. @jcubic

Comment: I don't understand what res is, you have mock in test but you don't show what it is in your real code where it came from, if res is fetch api mock it should look like this just this, but from your code it look that this is your internal thing and not part of the fetch api (stuff that is returned from `fetch()`) if so then you need        `onst res = { json: jest.fn(), status: jest.fn()};` because you don't call this like with fetch. If you want good answer you need to show the code your referring, right now it's not clear what res is and how it should be mocked.

Comment: @jcubic Is there a way I can directly contact you, as I have shown all the codes already. I think this is nodejs express res.json(),

Comment: There is chat on SO, it should be suggested by now I don't know the link.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to test the controller only, hence you should do

Update the controller to

```
var MondayModel = require('../models/mondayModel');


function createMondayBox(req, res, next) {
 ...
 var mondayModel = new MondayModel();
 mondayModel.createBox(req, payload, function(error, result) {

   if(error) {
     res.json({'status': 'BADREQUEST', 'statusCode': 400})

   } else {
     var mondaybox = result.resultSet.mondayboxes && 
     result.resultSet.mondayboxes[0]

     var mappedResponse = Response.mapCreateMondaybox(req, resultSet);
     utils.logKK(req, utils.getKK(mappedResponse.mondayboxes[0]))
     res.json(mappedResponse);
     next();
   }

  ...
 }
}
```

And in test file:

```
import {createRequest, createResponse}  from 'node-mocks-http'
import boxController from 'controller/boxController.js'
import mondayBoxModal from 'models/mondayBox';

jest.mock('models/mondayBox', () => () => ({ createBox: (req, payload, cb) => cb(null, { resultSet: { mondayboxes: ['resultsData']} } }));

describe('money tracker', () => {
 let req;
 let res;
 let next = jest.fn;
 beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
    req  = createRequest({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/user/42',
      params: {
       id: 42
      }
    });

    res = httpMocks.createResponse();
    res.json = jest.fn;

 })

 test('success case', done => {
   const req = {}

   mondayBoxController.createMondayBox(req, res, (cbErr, cbRes) => {
      expect(res.json).toBeCalled();
      done()
   })
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your function `transfer(req, res, next)` takes 3 argument and would use `res.json()` while your call `boxController.transfer(req, {}, fn)` is passing an empty object. It probably fails silently here.

And `transfer` didn't call next at all in your sample.

Please make sure your example resembles the actual code accurately.

**Update**

**It has nothing to do with async or not**

if you write this

```
const res = new Promise(r =>
  r({ json: jest.fn(), status: jest.fn() })
)
mondayBoxController.createMondayBox(req, res, (cbErr, cbRes) => {
  expect(res.json).toBeCalled();
  done();
})
```

then

```
mondayModel.createBox(req, payload, function (error, result) {
  console.log(res); // Promise, which has no json method
  console.log(res.json); // undefined
  // but
  console.log(await res); // the desired mocked res obj
  // btw this is incorrect usage of await
  if (error) {
    res.json();
  } else {
    ...
  }
});
```

`res` in `mondayModel.createBox`'s callback is exactly what you passed into `mondayBoxController.createMondayBox(req, res, handler)`.

instead, do this

```
const res = {
  json: jest.fn(); // or whatever behaviour you desire
};
mondayBoxController.createMondayBox(req, res, handler);
```

Comment: Good catch, didn't notice that res was not used actually but even that it will still not work, see my comment.

Comment: sorry, res = jest.fn(); boxController.transfer(req, res, fn) ... I wrote wrong in the code. Also, I have updated in the code, it should not transfer, is  boxController.createMondayBox. will try @jcubic said.

Comment: you need an object for `res` like `res = { json: jest.fn() }`